# Where can I find the google-webrtc source code?

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am developing Android webrtc, which relies on `google-webrtc`.
Where can I check its source code or documentation?

`implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'`

I found this plug-in in Maven，[bt-google-webrtc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webrtc/google-webrtc?repo=bt-google-webrtc), but there is no source code.

Or is there any other alternative to webrtc developed by Android?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably didn’t find it because most of Google’s source code are not stored on GitHub.

https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src.git

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally found the source code

Comment: Where did you find the source code .. please help